# see rails updated objects from params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to see all updated, changed objects that were updated from params hash, like so:
`current_user.events.update(params[:events].keys,params[:events].values)`

This updates all rows correctly, but I would like to get ids of all updated objects, and only these, so I can use them in Jquery to highlight only changed ones.
This is how params looks like:

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "events"=>{"334"=>{"name"=>"44232"}, "342"=>{"name"=>"1-2"}}}`

Comment: You want to highlight on the front-end if successful? Use your params, a JavaScript response and HTML id the events. Then use ERB in your JS to select events.

Comment: if you have `timestamps` on your `events` table, or whatever, you can check that created_at is equal to updated_at or no. if no, find the last updated (against last 1 minute/hour/day etc.) n events and highlight them.

Comment: I do not know a direct wy, but you can interate and use `.changed?` method and others like [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)